# What will be the size settings in photoshop of 4x6 feet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make a family tree more in font (minimum of 12pts) of 4x6 feet for a poster sticker so what will be the size settings in photoshop?

Comment: Also might be worth noting that Photoshop, although it could be used, is probably not the best software for such work.  A vector image editing application (such as Illustrator, Inskcape, CorelDraw) or page layout application (such as InDesign or Scribus) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in inches. So 4 x 6 feet = 48" x 72". The "Resolution" would ideally be 300 for print projects, although depending on your printing technique and personal preferences, you may be able to go as low as 150. Just know that the closer to 150 you are, the greater the chances the piece will be pixelated or fuzzy. And then set the Color Mode to CMYK, unless your printer directs you to use RGB instead. If you're not picky about the color, you can change this after you set the file up.

But I agree with Billy Kerr that a vector-based program would be better for this. You are likely to create a very large file size with these settings in Photoshop.

Here's a screenshot of the settings as described in this answer. Setting the Resolution as low as 150 may give you problems, so this might need to be adjusted to as high as 300. The best way to know for sure is to talk to a printer beforehand. They will tell you what resolution they can work with:

[image: A screenshot of the settings as described in this answer.]